# How to use OR in the PHP language

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if(!$con)
{
    die("not ok");
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"uoh");  
$q = "SELECT * FROM courses 
LEFT JOIN degree_plan ON degree_plan.course_number= courses.course_number 
LEFT JOIN student_record ON courses.course_number= student_record.course_number 
LEFT JOIN equal ON equal.sn= student_record.sn
AND student_record.id= 201102887
WHERE degree_plan.major='COE';";

$result = mysqli_query($con , $q ) ;
if($result){
   echo "<br />";
   echo "<table>";
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<th>id</th>";
   echo "</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
   if($row["id"]==201102887 || null)
   {
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>" . $row["id"]. "</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
   }
    else
  {} 
}
echo "</table>";
   }

?>
```

I have some code in my program and it works, but I have problem with `if($row["id"]==201102887 || null)` because it does not accept `null`, despite `null` being present in my database.

I want to make it so that if `id` is equal to `201102887` or `null` (no value) then the statements execute.

Comment: `$row["id"]==201102887 || $row["id"] == null`

Comment: `if($row["id"]==201102887 || null)` that isn't how it works. You need to use 2 separate statements.

Comment: Plus, if you're checking for probable empty rows, `null` != `empty` and *vice-versa*.

Comment: You can also use [is_null](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php) to check whether a variable is NULL

Comment: You can use `||` as or but you can also just use `OR` as or, both have the same effect. I know the question is already answered, but in case you didn't know that yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to use variables on both sides of the OR `||`
The code should be `if($row["id"]==201102887 || $row["id"]== null)`
This should work.

Answer (score 2):

use like that

```
if($row["id"]==201102887 || $row["id"]== null){

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `Logical operators` you should write two statements in if condition

**Statement 1 :** $row["id"] == 201102887

**Statement 2 :** $row["id"] == null

In if condition putt `||` between two statements

```
 if($row["id"]==201102887 || $row["id"]== null){
      // do something
    }
```

Another method of using `if`

```
     if($row["id"]==201102887 || $row["id"]== null):
      // do something
     endif;
```